# How do I checkout a repository inside a Docker container when using a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker

I've currently managed to set up a Jenkins file to run my PHP analysis inside a container. Here's the gist of it:

```
node {
    stage "Prepare environment"
        checkout scm
        def environment  = docker.build 'platforms-base'

        environment.inside {
            stage "Update Dependencies"
                sh "composer install || true"
        }
}
```

When this runs, it seems that the repo is checked out onto the host machine and that directory is mounted into the docker container in the `/app` directory. (I haven't found any configuration for this so I'm not sure where this is defined.)

In the same container, I have Magento2 installed in the `/var/magento2` directory. I need to run some tests inside the scope of the Magento2 codebase. This means that I need to checkout the current branch into a particular directory in the container at `/var/magento2/vendor/myorg/mypackage/` but the checked out repo seems to be at `/app`.

How do I checkout a repo in a certain place inside the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/app` will be mounted inside your container because you (or the Dockerfile you're using) mounts the current directory as `/app`.

Now, your code *is* already checked out just fine by Jenkins, so I wouldn't do a separate extra checkout from inside the docker container. Jenkins just checked out the correct branch/master/tag for you with the proper credentials, so no need to do it yourself.

You've got three basic choices:

- Mount the current directory not as `/app`, but as `/var/magento2/vendor/myorg/mypackage/`
- Mount the current directory as both `/app` and `/var/magento2/vendor/myorg/mypackage/`. You could perhaps even do this with an extra command line option instead of modifying the Dockerfile. (This very much depends on your development setup).
- Make `/var/magento2/vendor/myorg/mypackage/` a symlink to `/app`, that will probably work, too.